# Installed 2 versions of MS Office in the wrong order

Tags: microsoft-office

I had to make a quick change to an old Access '97 .mdb format file. [MDB Viewer Plus](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm) kept giving me syntax errors on the ALTER statement that it itself generated. IT just happened to have a  copy of Office '97 hidden away so I just went and installed it directly on top of my existing copy of Office 2013.

Unfortunately, I did not read any of the [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828956) [articles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2784668) ahead of time that would have explained what a bad idea that was. The Office '97 install seemed to fail and when it was done I could see a 0.12 MB file in Control Panel claiming to be Office '97. Since I was fairly certain that wasn't it, I removed it from there with plans to try a VM. But just on a whim, I tried to open the .mdb file in question and it opened up in Access '97 with no issues.

Now, because I installed them in the wrong order, my program associations are all sorts of strange. Old formats (xls, doc, mdb) open in Office '97 while new formats (xlsx, docx, accdb) open in Office 2013. I am unable to change these as can be seen below.

[image: Program associations locked]

So I would like to uninstall Office '97 and just put it in a VM. However, after I did the uninstall from Control Panel after the installation "failed", there is no way for me to remove it. Revo Uninstaller and CCleaner can't find it either.

What would be the cleanest way to try and fix this and remove Office '97? If I just delete the directory and run CCLeaner on the register, would that fix it? Or would Office 2013 have to come out as well and be reinstalled?

Comment: You cannot change them because of a group policy, talk to your IT department, so they can fix the problem.  You might also be able to switch it with just `open with` and selected Excel 2013, from the Excel installation directory.

Comment: @Ramhound We don't use group policies like that here. I can switch it with `open with` and all the icons in the directory change to the newer icon. Word complains that it is not the default for that type of file and lets me switch it. As soon as I close the document, all icons revert to the '97 icon and '97 regains default control.

Comment: Installing Office 2013 again might resolve your problem